# deserialize json into vb.net class with conditional definition

Tags: json, vb.net

I am an intermediate programmer and am trying to find a solution to a JSON deserialize issue in vb.net. I'm working some product updates with an API (not mine) in which I have to get the product, deserialize it, change some values, and post an update.

I have built out a bunch of vb.net classes to handle the deserialize (newtonsoft.json) of a JSON doc and for the most part works great. However, I ran into a situation on some products where the object could be defined one of two ways depending on the value of a particular json object.

Here is a snippet of the JSON:

```
"PriceGrids": [
{
  "IsBasePrice": false,
  "PriceConfigurations": [
    {
      "Criteria": "Imprint Method",
      "Value": [
        "SILKSCREEN"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "IsBasePrice": true,
  "PriceConfigurations": [
    {
      "Criteria": "Size",
      "Value": [
        {
          "Attribute": "Length",
          "Value": "25",
          "Unit": "cm"
        },
        {
          "Attribute": "Width",
          "Value": "7.5",
          "Unit": "cm"
        },
        {
          "Attribute": "Height",
          "Value": "14.5",
          "Unit": "cm"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So Value has two definitions depending on the IsBasePrice value (true/false). I currently have Value defined in the class as below.

```
Private _Value As New List(Of String)
Public Property Value() As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _Value
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        _Value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This, of course, fails when it isn't a list of string(s). I can't find an example anywhere of handling this. Is it even possible in vb.net to handle a conditional object definition based on the Json provided?

Comment: Do these different types need to be included in the same POST? Maybe you can post more than once (different objects). Sounds weird, though. You could also prepare a custom type converter. **But**, since you have one class that needs to hold, at the same time, different properties, the first *type* (`"Value": [ "SILKSCREEN" ]`) will have empty properties values anyway. No way to know whether this can be accepted on the receiver side without testing. BTW, the JSON, as it is here, is not valid.

Comment: Sorry about the invalid json code. I tried my best to take a snippet of the code that worked with the post to convey the point. And sadly, yes they have to be included in the return post, otherwise the API on their other end creates a new product entry, instead of updating the existing one causing dupe entries. My initial thought was to ignore the field on deserialization, but since it is required back, that wasn't an option.

Comment: Well, you could also simply define Value as an `IList(Of Object)`. That would both deserialize and serialize without *questions* on what is being submitted. If you want, I can post a sample of the classes that could be used with the JSON (fixed) you posted here. But, of course, I have no means to test it, so...

Comment: I'm going to give it a try and test it later today. Ty for offering a sample.

Comment: I actually tested this solution with the JSON you posted here and it deserialized correctly. Of course, it also serializes correctly: the output JSON is exactly as the input's.

Comment: This works perfectly. Ty Jimi!